# Print checkerboard pattern array C

Tags: arrays, c

I am doing more practice on arrays, and this time I am using the print function with an online debugger to give me better insight. There is a main nested loop that loops 64 times to fill the array cells with the team value, furthermore this is passed to an if else statement which determines if the value of the cell will be either 1 or 2. Next the row and cell of the array is determined, and the number is assigned inside the cell. The print works but it only prints an array of one number. Using GDB for compiler online.

I edited the code throughly through the past weeks while compiling my project. This example was used to test out the functionality of the array logic I designed. I changed up a short circuit boolean error, and I corrected the array index of my program, but the visuals seem to only print the same value. Why is this still happening?

Is this because of a pointer issue? I believe my issues are on the visual aspect of the code with the print function.
Original

```
#include <stdio.h>

int row;
int col;
int myrowcol[7][7];
int team;
int green = 2;
int red = 1;

void main()
{
    for (int game = 0; game < 64; game++)
    {
        if (game % 2 == 0)
        {
            team = red;
        }
        else
            team = green;

        for (int col = 7; col >= 0; col--)
        {
            for (int row = 7; row >= 0; row--)
            {
                if (myrowcol[col][row - 1] != 0 || row == 0)
                {
                    myrowcol[col][row] = team;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        {
            printf("%d ", myrowcol[col][row] = team);
        }

        printf("\n"); // new line
    }
}
```

New

[New image results][1]

Please note that the patter should change based on rows, alternating between one and two. The columns should consist of the same number, either one or two.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int row;
int col;
int myrowcol[8][8];
int teamturn = 0;
int selectGame()
{
    for(; teamturn < 64; teamturn++)
    {
      if (teamturn %2 ==0)
       {
         return 1;
       }
      else return 2;
    }
}
int Turn()
{
for (int col = 0; col <= 7; col--)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row <= 7; row--)
            {
                if (row == 0 || myrowcol[col][row - 1] != 0)
                {
                    myrowcol[col][row] = selectGame();
                    teamturn++;
                    return myrowcol[col][row];
                }
            }
        }
}
void main()
{
    int selectGame();
    int Turn();
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        {
            printf("%d", myrowcol[col][row]=selectGame());
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGEdz.png
```

Comment: Google short-circuit boolean evaluation, then consider the difference of `if (myrowcol[col][row - 1] != 0 || row == 0)` vs. `if (row == 0 || myrowcol[col][row - 1] != 0)`.  And the `8` hand-coded limits are an obvious recipe for a breach in the last two loops. You basically breach your declared dimensions with *all* of this code in one way or another. Question: are you aware that array indexing in `C` is zero-based. E.g. for an array dimensions `arr[7]` the only legal index values are 0..6 inclusively? If not, get a book on C, because it's covered in even the worst of them.

Comment: Additionally, "There is a main nested loop that loops 64 times to get the array size" is nonsense. You already know the sizing of your array of arrays; it is hard-declared at `int myrowcol[7][7];` . And there are 49 addressable elements; not 64. And even if all of that is fixed somehow, the final nested loop that repeats `printf("%d ", myrowcol[col][row] = team);` is probably not doing what you think it is. It just repeatedly stores the same `team` value in every cell whilst also sending it to stdout. As I said, *get a good book on C*.

Comment: Why are all of your variables globals?  None of them should be (except constants, which should either be macros or else declared const).

Comment: The nested loops in the first loop don't really make sense.  Plus you're indexing out of bounds.  Hint:  If `row` is zero, then what is `row - 1`?  Is it a valid index?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, for a second I thought that it followed something like VHDL with `arr[7]` being the same as `std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);` Took a step back from C for a year

Comment: @TomKarzes Are you talking about `row--` in the for loop or are you talking about my array index `if (myrowcol[col][row-1] ! = 0)`? If the second, I noticed that so I did a boolean operation `if (myrowcol[col][row-1] ! = 0 || row == 0)`

Comment: *"so I did a boolean operation if (myrowcol[col][row-1] ! = 0 || row == 0)"* - which leads to my first comment about short circuit boolean evaluation. It processes left to right and stops as soon as the complete expression result is determine regardless of further evaluations. Therefore, you want range checks *before* indexing evals; not after. Or... since all you're doing is generating a checkerboard, [why not just do this](https://godbolt.org/z/PK4K4szaE). Or even more concise, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/n138EjrWz).

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't understand why this is an issue. I see where you are coming from, but if any output from an or expression is 1 then logically speaking, the output will be 1. (1 || x) = 1. Can you explain how the range check would look? Are you talking about `if (row == 0 || myrowcol[col][row - 1] != 0)` ?

Comment: @RyanPaye The following expression is undefined behavior within your loop:  `myrowcol[col][row - 1] != 0 || row == 0`  The first thing it does when it evaluates this is index into `myrowcol`.  This indexes past the row bounds, and if `col` is zero as well, it indexes right out of the array.  This could cause a segmentation fault.  The fact that you check if `row == 0` after the invalid memory access will at best give you consistent result, *provided* the program doesn't die first.  It's a severe bug that you should learn to spot instantly.  Check `row == 0` *before* the invalid memory access.

Comment: @RyanPaye Here's an analogy for you:  Suppose you blast through an intersection while driving, then once through it you look back to see if the light was red.  Is that safe?

Comment: Your insight into arrays is seemingly only "skin deep". While it is a good idea to learn by doing, SO is commonly not the place to chat about this. This is a question-and-answer site, you might want to take the [tour] (again). A better place would be any decent forum for beginners in C, where you can discuss anything.